# KeepAlive HTTP Requests on Appengine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, node.js, keep-alive

Is it possible to have a HTTP keep-alive Request on Google Appengine much like node.js ?

Comment: HTTP Keepalive is for maintaining a connection between a client and a server independent of requests. I presume you actually intended to ask about comet / long-polling?

Comment: @NickJohnson Yeah i was not aware of that terminology but long pull request method solved the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the channels ([Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview.html), [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html)) service which uses the long pull request (comet) method.